# SYNTAX ERROR ")" ON DATE RANGE

Tags: formula, compile-error

I'm trying to segregate records by month name for the first three months of the year. Everything with a date range of `1/1/19` through `1/31/19`, should return `JAN`, for example.

I'm getting syntax errors of a missing parenthesis. Here's what I wrote:

```
IF(AND(Application__c.CreatedDate>=(2019,1,19),Application__c.CreatedDate<=(2019,1,31)),"JAN",IF(AND(Application__c.CreatedDate<=(2019,2,1),Application__c.CreatedDate<=(2019,2,18)),"FEB",IF(AND(Application__c.CreatedDate>=(2019,3,1),Application__c.CreatedDate<=(2019,3,31)),"MAR","")))
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a `CASE` function. Its much easier to write. Also, it will avoid issue in leap year.

```
CASE(MONTH(PO_Received_Date__c),
1, "January",
2, "February",
3, "March", 
4, "April", 
5, "May", 
6, "June",
7, "July",
8, "August",
9, "September",
10, "October",
11, "November",
12, "December",
"None")
```

Comment: Thank you. These are helpful comments. Now I receive an incorrect parameter message: Warning
Incorrect parameter type for function 'MONTH()'. Expected Date, received Object

Comment: the variable that you are using in Month Function is not a date

Answer (score 1):

> `Application__c.CreatedDate>=(2019,3,1)`

`(2019,3,1)` isn't a valid date format. In formulas, to create dates, you need to use the `DATE(year,month,day)`. You can fix your code by adding `DATE` to your date values.

`Application__c.CreatedDate >= DATE(2019, 3 ,1)`

Issues with your code aside, it makes much more sense to use `CASE` on the `MONTH` of the date field instead.